# Automapper Configuration in Global.asax issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I have an MVC4 application (.NET 4.5). I have two data classes in this project:

```
public class Address
{
    public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    public DateTime InsertTimeStamp { get; set; }
    public bool IsProcessed { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ProcessedTimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

I am using AutoMapper to map from OrderDetail to Address class as shown below

```
public class OrderDetailToAddressMappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<OrderDetail, Address>();
    }
}

public static class AutoMapperMvcConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.AddProfile<OrderDetailToAddressMappingProfile>();
                x.AddProfile<AddressToPropertyAddressMappingProfile>();
            });
    }
}
```

I am calling AutoMapperMvcConfiguration.Configure() in my global.asax class. When I run this application and get to the code where I am trying to do a mapping from OrderDetail object to Address object I get the following exception:

"Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping".

It seems as if Global.asax class's Application_Start is not getting fired. I tried the following three things to come to this conclusion:

1. I tried to debug by putting a break point but the code doesn't break in global.asax. I am aware that Application_Start is only fired once so before debugging I stopped the internal VS web server but it still doesn't break.
2. I used Mapper.FindTypeMapFor() just before the mapping code and get null back.
3. If I break just before the mapping code and manually call AutoMapperMvcConfiguration.Configure(), I don't see this mapping issue.

Not sure why Application_Start is not firing. I don't understand how my MVC application can run okay without Application_Start being fired as the routing register method is also being called from Application_Start.

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Update 1:

Here is the code where mapping is used:

```
    public ActionResult Process(int orderId)
    {
        OrderDetail orderDetail = _hydrantFlowOrderAccessor.GetHydrantFlowOrderById(orderId);

        if (orderDetail != null)
        {
            Address address = Mapper.Map<OrderDetail, Address>(orderDetail);
            GeoLocation geoLocation = _geoDataAccessor.GetGeoLocation(Mapper.Map<Address, PropertyAddress>(address));

            IEnumerable<FlowTest> flowTests =
                _hydrantFlowDataAccessor.GetFlowTestByAddress(address);

            Process processModel = new Process
            {
                FlowTests = flowTests,
                StreetName = address.StreetName,
                Latitude = geoLocation.Latitude,
                Longitude = geoLocation.Longitude
            };

            return View(processModel);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Stack Trace:

[AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
OrderDetail -> Address
ISO.NPCEfficiencies.DashBoard.Models.HydrantFlows.OrderDetail -> ISO.NPCEfficiencies.DashBoard.Models.HydrantFlows.Address

Destination path:
Address

Source value:
ISO.NPCEfficiencies.DashBoard.Models.HydrantFlows.OrderDetail]
   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context) +861
   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map(Object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType, Action`1 opts) +196
   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map(TSource source) +257
   AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(TSource source) +107
   ISO.NPCEfficiencies.DashBoard.Controllers.HydrantFlowController.Process(Int32 orderId) in g:\Projects\Visual Studio 2012\NPCDashBoard\ISO.NPCEfficiencies.DashBoard\Controllers\HydrantFlowController.cs:60
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +161
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +211
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass13.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__10() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +253
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass15.b*_12() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +324
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1d.b*_19() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629708
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Update 2:

Global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : SpringMvcApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AutoMapperMvcConfiguration.Configure();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Comment: EDIT: Uggghh. I really should learn to read the questions properly. Paste the entire Automapper message here.

Comment: Please share the code where you use the mapping and the full stack trace of the exception (not just the message).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Added the stack trace.

Comment: @AntP: Shared the code using the mapping and the stack trace.

Comment: This all looks fine to me. This is exactly how we use Automapper on the project I am involved in now. Can you show us your Global.asax?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: I am away from my work PC but the only thing that I added to my Global.asax's Application_Start method is AutoMapperMvcConfiguration.Configure() call.

Comment: Does your Global class inherit from anything else? Or is it stock standard?

Comment: I should have mentioned this. The global.asax class is inheriting the SpringMvcApplication class. I am using Spring.Net in my project.

Comment: Can you share your global.asax code?

Comment: Do you host your code at IIS server, or you use local IIS express?

Comment: @EfrainReyes: Shared my global.asax code

Comment: @RomanPushkin: I am using VS's internal web server (IIS Express).

Comment: This looks fine to me in terms of configuring Automapper. Try cleaning out your `bin/` directory, restart Visual Studio - this usually helps with `App_Start()` not getting hit.

Comment: Change your application start to `public void Application_Start( object sender, EventArgs e )`

Comment: @trailmax: Cleaning the bin folder didn't help

Comment: @WiktorZychla: I couldn't change to public void Application_Start(...) as I got a warning that it hides the same method in the SpringMvcApplication class. Then I tried to override the Application_Start virtual method in SpringMvcApplication by changing the method signature to protected override void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) and that did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried changing the Application_Start method's signature to

```
public void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

as suggested by @WiktorZychla but I got a warning that it hides the same method in the SpringMvcApplication class. Then I tried to override the Application_Start virtual method in SpringMvcApplication by changing the method signature to

```
protected override void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and that did the trick.